# How to modify this HTML form to include a constant?

Tags: html, forms

Here's an example of a search in our SirsiDynix Enterprise catalog using the CloudSourceOA option te=750777545
https://nyit.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/default/search/results?qu=html&te=750777545&rt=false%7C%7C%7C%3ECSOA%3Ctitle%7C%7C%7CTitle

I want to pass the variables from a form in libguides to the enterprise. I have a working example for searching "Everything" and a broken example for the CloudSourceOA
My Form sends the search types like title and the term that the user enters in the input field to the qu=, however, I don't know how to append the te=750777545. This value will always be set as I want the widget to always search cloudsource rather than everything.
Here's a link to my libguide for troubleshooting. I was unable to add the code successfully here.
https://libguides.nyit.edu/c.php?g=1216772&p=8899584&preview=77a637b8476d8bbe2575a12fd18e3b61

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what `te` or the `750777545` value is, but if you need to hardcode that to your form you can do so with a hidden input set to that value. Fair warning, without knowing what this form field is, this may not be the best approach so you'll want to consult any documentation if this is specific to an internal NYIT application.

```html
<form action="https://nyit.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/default/search/results?" id="searchForm" method="&te=&quot;&quot;get&quot;" name="searchForm">
    <h5>Search the NYIT Catalogue</h5>
    <div class="searchline">
        <input name="ln" type="hidden" value="en_US"><br>
        <select class="dropDown" id="restrictionDropDown" name="rt">
            <option value="">
                All Fields
            </option>
            <option value="false|||TITLE|||Title">
                Title
            </option>
            <option value="false|||AUTHOR|||AUTHOR">
                Author
            </option>
            <option value="false|||SUBJECT|||SUBJECT">
                Subject
            </option>
            <option value="false|||ISBN|||ISBN">
                ISBN
            </option>
            <option value="false|||ISSN|||ISSN">
                ISSN
            </option>
            <option value="false|||DOI|||DOI">
                DOI
            </option>
            <option value="false|||JOURNAL|||Journal Title">
                Journal Title
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="te" name="te" value="750777545"> 
        <p><input accesskey="s" id="qu" maxlength="256" name="qu" style="width:250px;" title="Search For:" type="text" value=""><input class="button" id="searchButton" title="Search" type="submit" value="Search"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```